# How to pass props from <Route /> to a component

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

Even after using the render option in the  component, the component inside render is not receiving an new prop.

Have checked if other default props are accessible and they are.

**Layout.js:**

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="*"
    render={(props) => <HomeComponent {...props} loc={constants["404"]} />}
  />
</Switch>
```

**HomeComponent.js:**

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.loc) // Output is shown as undefined
}
```

I expect the prop loc to be filled with the data for 404 page, but receiving **undefined**

Comment: Found the issue. When we use both component and render option in <Route />, the component prop takes precedence and the new props sent to "HomeComponent" via render option is not considered.